# invalid hook call on data retrieved by axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I'm trying to retrieve the JSON data from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) and then update the state in a functional component. Even though the code seems fine I'm getting an error saying its an invalid hook call.

On the react documentation it said that I might have 2 different react apps in the same folder however I checked it with the command they gave and there was only 1. However I am running this from a django server and there is a different react app in a different django app (so in a completely different folder).

```
const App = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    axios.get(url).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
      // The code crashes here saying that it is an invalid hook call
      useState(res.data);
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      This is just a place holder.
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a feeling this might have something to do with the other react application in the django project but if anyone can see something that I can't I would appreciate the help.

***Edit***
I realised that I was trying to call useState() in the useEffect hook when I should have been using the setPosts function that was already defined in the function.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>   // The code crashes here saying that it is an invalid hook call
> ```

It crashes there because you are not using the state hook correctly. You should call `setPosts` instead of `useState`. See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Comment: oh my that is such a stupid mistake it has been a long day xD